# The 'this' context of type 'Subject<void>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am importing `Subject` from `rxjs` and then creating a property `onSentenceChangeDebouncer`. In the constructor I am using `this` so I am not sure why I am getting the error "is not assignable to method". It looks like it is related to the line with `debounceTime(300)`.

```
Error   TS2684  The 'this' context of type 'Subject<void>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<void>'.
  The types returned by 'lift(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'R'.
        'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.
```

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

onSentenceChangeDebouncer: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

constructor(
  this.onSentenceChangeDebouncer
    .debounceTime(300)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.updateConceptDependencies();
      this.compileSentence();
    });
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzw1ze?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you subscribe to the `Subject<T>` instead of `Observable<T>`. The corrected code should be:

```js
onSentenceChange$: Observable<void> = this.onSentenceChangeDebouncer.asObservable();

this.onSentenceChange$.debounceTime(300).subscribe(() => { ... });
```

As it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72363934/577167), the error happens due to the fact that the `Subject<T>.lift` signature was broken in the package until v5.4.2, so it's also possible to get rid of it by updating `rxjs` to that version.

Comment: So I should be using v5.4.2?

Comment: Yes, I would upgrade to v5.4.2.

Answer (score 4):

you put your code on the wrong scope, u probably want to do it like this:

```
 constructor() {
 this.onSentenceChangeDebouncer
            .debounceTime(300)
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.updateConceptDependencies();
                this.compileSentence();
            });
}
```

Comment: I updated the post with a sample of the error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzw1ze?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: did you see the update stackblitz with the error?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT
this work with rxjs +6.0

you forgot to pipe the subject! try this:

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

onSentenceChangeDebouncer: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

onSentenceChangeDebouncer$ = this.onSentenceChangeDebouncer.pipe(
            .debounceTime(300)
            )
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.updateConceptDependencies();
                this.compileSentence();
            });

 constructor(){}
```

i suggest you to not subscribe in constructor, but prefer the onInit Hook or, like in example, directly in the contest of the component.

in this way you have the reactivness that you need

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your constructor is missing this closing ')' your code should look something like this:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";


class SomeClass {
    onSentenceChangeDebouncer: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
    
    constructor() {
        this.onSentenceChangeDebouncer
            .debounceTime(300)
            .subscribe(() => {
            
            
               this.updateConceptDependencies();
               this.compileSentence();
            });

    }

    updateConceptDependencies() { /* some logic */ }
    compileSentence() { /* some logic */ }

}
```

Comment: I updated the pos with a sample of the error

Comment: did you see the update stackblitz with the error?